# Make terraform module creation fail based on a condition

Tags: terraform

I am trying to leverage `precondition` hook to check for an input to a `module` creation in `terraform`.

```
module "groups" {

  source   = "../path/to/groups"
  for_each = var.groups.groups

  name     = each.key
  type     = each.value.type
  policies = each.value.policies
  depends_on = [
    module.policies
  ]
  
  lifecycle {

    precondition {
      condition = alltrue([ for item in self.policies : 
      alltrue([ for p in item : contains(locals.policies_list, p) ]) ] ) 
      error_message = format("Attempt to create a group with a non existing policy")
    }
  }

}
```

However, although:

```
terraform --version --json
{
  "terraform_version": "1.3.7",
  "platform": "linux_amd64",
  "provider_selections": {},
  "terraform_outdated": false
}
```

This fails:

```
The block type name "lifecycle" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version.
```

Is this because the specific functionality is not available in `terraform` for `module` creation? Is there a way around making my module creation fail based on the above condition?

Comment: I guess you could create a local variable that does the same evaluation you have in your `condtion`. Then, in `for_each`, you could do something like `for_each = local.condition ? var.groups.groups : []`.

Comment: Yes that is a way around but I would also like the process to error out explicitly

Comment: If it is not available now, maybe it will be at a later stage and maybe it is even available as an experimental feature: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings#experimental-language-features.

Comment: Why not use a variable validation block in the declaration for `var.groups`?

Comment: The values to be checked against are not a priori known, these are values created dynamically from another resource (a module that creates the `policies`)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `lifecycle` block is not available for a `module`.

A way around this is the following

```
module "groups" {

  source   = "../path/to/groups"
  for_each = var.groups.groups

  name     = each.key
  type     = each.value.type
  policies = each.value.policies
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.group_check,
    module.policies
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "group_check" {
  for_each = var.groups.groups

  lifecycle {

    precondition {
      condition     = alltrue([for p in each.value.policies : contains(local.policies_list, p)])
      error_message = format("Attempt to create a group with a non existing policy")
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    module.policies
  ]
}
```